# How to send hid data to android device? (Using python)

Tags: python, android, mouse, hid

I want to send hid data (from a mouse and a keyboard) from a windows computer to an android device. What is the general approach I should take for this?

What would such a hid packet look like?

OS: windows

target device: android 6.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send HID data to your Android device from Python, you can use the `pyhidapi` library. Here is some help on how to use it:

1st step:
Install the pyhidapi library:

```
pip install pyhidapi
```

Second step:
Import the modules:

```
import hid
import time
```

Third step: Find the hid device:

```
vendor_id = 0x1234  # Replace with your HID device's vendor ID
product_id = 0x6969  # Replace with your HID device's product ID

# Get the list of connected HID devices
devices = hid.enumerate(vendor_id, product_id)

if len(devices) == 0:
    print("Nope, no Hid devices.")
    exit()

device_info = devices[0]
device_path = device_info['path']
device = hid.device()
device.open_path(device_path)
```

Fourth step: Send HID data:

```
report_id = 0x01  # Replace with your HID report ID
data = [0x00, 0x01, 0x02]  # Replace with the data you want to send

# Prepare the data to be sent 
if report_id is not None:
    data.insert(0, report_id)

# Send the data to the phone

device.write(data)


time.sleep(0.1) 

# Close the connection
device.close()
```

i hope this helps you send stuff to your phone from python.

Comment: Also this code isn't the best example. I think there is better info about the pyhidapi on other sources like the library's documentation on https://github.com/apmorton/pyhidapi

Comment: Thank you, your answer was informative. I was also looking into the interrupt and read signals (from or for a mouse). What would this data look like? Is it driver dependent?

Comment: Hello i am only using pyhidapi to send keyboard input (i was making a custom game controller) so i dont know how to send mouse siginals with this library but i think there is a simpler library for mouse input somewhere